# How to use intent to pass string to main activity once timer runs out?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to use intents to set an edittext on my main activity equal to a textview on my second activity.  The second activity has a button that when pressed starts a timer counting down from 10 seconds, and counts each time the button is pressed.  After the 10 seconds are up, I want to take the value of the textview (set by how many times the button was pressed), set the edittext on the main activity equal to it, and go back to the main activity.

The idea is that you can manually enter a count on the main activity, or use the built in timer to help you count.

My app is crashing upon opening, I have tried multiple ways to do this to no avail.  I think the problem may be stemming from the onCreate on the main activity "looking for" the intent, but it's not there since it is running when the button on the second activity is pressed.

**Main activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    qtyInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtyInput);
    valueInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueInput);
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String clickCount = intent.getExtras().getString("clickCount");
    qtyInput.setText(clickCount);

    Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float qty = Float.parseFloat(qtyInput.getText().toString());
            float value = Float.parseFloat(valueInput.getText().toString());
            float total = qty * value * 60;
            String stringTotal = String.format("%.0f", total);
            resultText.setText(stringTotal);
        }
    });

    Button countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countButton);
    countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CountActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**Second activity**

```
    final TextView countdownTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);

    final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            countdownTimer.setText("Time left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            String clickCount = countDisplay.getText().toString();
            final Intent passCount = new Intent(CountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            passCount.putExtra("clickCount", clickCount);
            startActivity(passCount);
        }
    };

    final TextView countDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDisplay);
        int count;

    Button countOneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countOneButton);
    countOneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (clickcount==0) {
                timer.start();
                clickcount++;
                countDisplay.setText("Count: " + clickcount);
            }
             else {
                clickcount++;
                countDisplay.setText("Count: " + clickcount);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to take the value of the textview (set by how many times the
>   button was pressed), set the edittext on the main activity equal to
>   it, and go back to the main activity.

Two ways to get data back in `MainActivity` from `CountActivity` :

**1.** With current code call `MainActivity.this.finish()` after starting `CountActivity` Activity.

```
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CountActivity.class));
   MainActivity.this.finish();
```

**2.** Start `CountActivity` Activity using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` and override `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity` get data back from `CountActivity`. to send data call `setResult` method before finishing `CountActivity` Activity.

```
Intent passCount = new Intent();
passCount.putExtra("clickCount", clickCount);
CountActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,passCount);
CountActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: OK that makes sense.  I looked into how to use startActivityForResult and that seems to be the best way to make this work for me.  I've been messing around with it and I think I'm close, but it's now crashing for me when the timer runs out and it should go back to mainactivity.  I put the code for returnIntent into the onFinish codeblock within the countdown timer.  Is that the correct placement?

Comment: Also, how do you override onActivityResult?

Comment: @gah4716: see following example for help [Android Start Activity for Result Example](http://techblogon.com/android-start-activity-for-result-example/)